# How to sort Python list with date

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list in Python like this

```
myList = ['http://google.com Google 2018-07-10', 'http://apple.com Apple Inc 2018-07-11', 'http://microsoft.com Microsoft 2018-07-12']
```

i want to sort this list by the dates

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: yes, i've tried to sort dictionary before appending but my dictionary's key values are always changing so i couldn't figure it out with list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that should work in a more general case:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

myList = [
    'http://google.com Google 2018-07-10',
    'http://apple.com Apple Inc 2018-07-11',
    'Foo 2017-07-13 http://whatever.com',
    'http://microsoft.com Microsoft 2018-07-12',
    '2015-07-15 http://whatever.com Whatever'
]

dct = {parse(v, fuzzy=True): v for v in myList}
print([dct[k] for k in sorted(dct, reverse=True)])
print([dct[k] for k in sorted(dct)])
```

This way you won't be forced to have dates at the end of the list strings, output:

```
['http://microsoft.com Microsoft 2018-07-12', 'http://apple.com Apple Inc 2018-07-11', 'http://google.com Google 2018-07-10', 'Foo 2017-07-13 http://whatever.com', '2015-07-15 http://whatever.com Whatever']
['2015-07-15 http://whatever.com Whatever', 'Foo 2017-07-13 http://whatever.com', 'http://google.com Google 2018-07-10', 'http://apple.com Apple Inc 2018-07-11', 'http://microsoft.com Microsoft 2018-07-12']
```

Comment: thank you! but could you please explain me how python handle random list data in to dictionary like this?

Answer (score 2):

Using `sorted` with `lambda` in `key`

**Ex:**

```
myList = ['http://google.com Google 2018-07-10', 'http://apple.com Apple Inc 2018-07-11', 'http://microsoft.com Microsoft 2018-07-12']

print( sorted(myList, key= lambda x: x.split()[-1], reverse=True) )
print( sorted(myList, key= lambda x: x.split()[-1]) )
```

**Output:**

```
['http://microsoft.com Microsoft 2018-07-12', 'http://apple.com Apple Inc 2018-07-11', 'http://google.com Google 2018-07-10']
['http://google.com Google 2018-07-10', 'http://apple.com Apple Inc 2018-07-11', 'http://microsoft.com Microsoft 2018-07-12']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split each string, take the last part, and sort by this part:

```
myList = [
    'http://apple.com Apple Inc 2018-07-11', 
    'http://google.com Google 2018-07-10',     
    'http://microsoft.com Microsoft 2018-07-12'
]

sorted(myList, key=lambda s: s.split()[-1])
```

Output:

```
['http://google.com Google 2018-07-10',
 'http://apple.com Apple Inc 2018-07-11',
 'http://microsoft.com Microsoft 2018-07-12']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also sort the list by applying [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to `key`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> myList = ['http://google.com Google 2018-07-10', 'http://apple.com Apple Inc 2018-07-11', 'http://microsoft.com Microsoft 2018-07-12']
>>> sorted(myList, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.split()[-1], '%Y-%m-%d'))
['http://google.com Google 2018-07-10', 'http://apple.com Apple Inc 2018-07-11', 'http://microsoft.com Microsoft 2018-07-12']
```

**Note:** This might be over complicating it slightly, since ISO formats dates, and sorts string dates perfectly fine, as shown in the other answers. Using `strptime()` is to just ensure that the dates are sorted by correct date format.